# Creating a Alert component which can be called from other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this Alert component

```
class Alert extends Component {

  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      body: "hello"
    }
  }

  show = (body)=> {
    this.setState({
      body: body
    });
  }
  render() {

    return <div>{this.state.body}</div>
  }

}
export default Alert;
```

I need to call this Alert like

```
Alert.show("I am new text");
```

I did like this which is not working

```
import Alert from './Alert';
class SomeClass extends Component {

  someFunc = ()=> {
     Alert.show("I am new text");
  }

}
```

I know its possible, seen calls like `toast.warn(...)` from `react-toastify`

Am I doing something wrong, how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass ref to call child method.

```
// parent component

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Alert from "./tab";

class ComponentTwo extends React.Component {
  changeAlert = () => {
    this.refs.Alert.show("I am new text");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div onClick={this.changeAlert}>Click Me</div>
        <Alert ref="Alert" />
      </>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ComponentTwo />, rootElement);
```

And the child component

```
import React from "react";

class Alert extends React.Component {
  state = {
    body: "hello"
  };

  show = body => {
    this.setState({
      body: body
    });
  };
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.body}</div>;
  }
}
export default Alert;
```

Example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/9lk3r4j64r

Comment: This works, but there has to be another method to do it without refs. An example would be toast https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify#one-component-to-rule-them-all  They just include `<ToastContainer />` in app root and call it from anywhere